# Div background wrong when cascading divs

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple HTML/CSS sample in JSFiddle to show my problem.  I want to have multiple section among themselves. Each section should have a width of 100% and the content area within this section 978 px.

In general my HTML/CSS seems to work, but when i want to add multiple DIVs within another DIV (content) and align one on the left (blog) the other one on the right side (sidebar), then something is going wrong with the background of the wrapper (content-wrapper). I ave the same background for content-wrapper and about-wrapper. Both are gray. But the content-wrapper background color must be green.

My question:

- Whats wrong with my HTML/CSS: Why do i have for both wrapper the same background color even if i have set to a different color in my CSS?
- Is this a good HTML/CSS for this layout?

HTML

```
<div class="page-wrapper">

  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header center">header</div>
  </div>

  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content center">
      <div class="blog">
        blog
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        sidebar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  

  <div class="about-wrapper">
    <div class="about center">about</div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-wrapper">
    <div class="footer center">footer</div>
  </div>

</div> <!-- end page-wrapper -->
```

CSS

```
.page-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.center {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 100px; 
}

.blog {
  float: left;
  width: 678px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
}

.header-wrapper {background-color:yellow;width:100%;}
.content-wrapper {background-color:green;width:100%;}
.about-wrapper {background-color:gray;width:100%;}
.footer-wrapper {background-color:blue;width:100%;}

.header {
  width: 978px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  width: 978px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.about {
  width: 978px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.footer {
  width: 978px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1f867k3v/

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? I have build an example, i have clearly asked my question, i have posted also an jsfiddle and yes, i have tried to find the error, but couldnt. If you downvote, then add any comment or make any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nothing but floating children inside your `.content` block, so it collapses to zero height. You need to add `.clearfix` to fix that:

```css
.page-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.center {
     margin: 0 auto;
     width: 100px; 
}

.blog {
  float: left;
  width: 678px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
}

.header-wrapper {background-color:yellow;width:100%;}
.content-wrapper {background-color:green;width:100%;}
.about-wrapper {background-color:gray;width:100%;}
.footer-wrapper {background-color:blue;width:100%;}

.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.header {
  width: 978px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  width: 978px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.about {
  width: 978px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.footer {
  width: 978px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">

  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header center">header</div>
  </div>

  <div class="content-wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="content center clearfix">
      <div class="blog">
        blog
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar">
        sidebar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="about-wrapper">
    <div class="about center">about</div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer-wrapper">
    <div class="footer center">footer</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

*Is this a good HTML/CSS for this layout?*

Answer depends on who you ask - personally, I would use flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS `.content` class add `overflow: hidden` will work your code. But here I have modified as per the HTML 5 and CSS 3 features. Your code followed HTML 4 and CSS 2.

```
<div class="page-wrapper">

  <header class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="center">header</div>
  </header>

  <content class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="blog">
       blog
    </section>
    <aside class="sidebar">
       sidebar
    </aside>
  </content>  

  <div class="about-wrapper">
    <div class="center">about</div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer-wrapper">
    <div class="center">footer</div>
  </footer>

</div> <!-- end page-wrapper -->
```

CSS

```
.page-wrapper {
  width:100%;
}

.center {
  text-align:center; 
}

.blog {
  flex: 2;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 1;
}

.header-wrapper {background-color:yellow;}
.content-wrapper {background-color:green;display:flex;}
.about-wrapper {background-color:gray;}
.footer-wrapper {background-color:blue;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5x8qsnet/